# Compare integers by using for loop

Tags: python

I'm python newbie and got a problem while doing some practices.

Below is the code that I've got so far:

```
def gt(nums, n):
    for c in nums:
        if n < c:
            return True
        elif c < n:
            return False
        else:
            break
```

With above code, it does not return properly.
The examples of correct answers here:

```
gt([1,2,3],3) => False
gt([1,2,3],2) => True
```

Comment: What is the goal of the function? `gt` is not a very descriptive name. Are you trying to see if `n` is larger than all numbers in the list? Or less? Or ..?

Comment: it appears to be "is any element in nums greater than n"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simpler and more readable solution would be the following:

```
def gt(lst, n):
    return max(lst) > n
```

Comment: ... except that this always looks at all elements in the comparison list, where Mario's `any` solution can stop as soon as a contrary example is found.

Comment: @Hugh: Both solutions are `O(n)` in the worst and average case. In practice using `max` will usually be faster because it's implemented in C. Also, who cares about performance in Python anyway? I definitely rate simplicity over efficiency when coding in a high-level language. Mario's solution is simple and readable as well, though :)

Comment: Forget about the "faster" part, it's actually not very relevant which one is faster and it highly depends on the input

Answer (score 4):

using a one liner

```
def gt(nums, n):
    return any(e > n for e in nums)
```

this breaks when the first element bigger than n is found.

Answer (score 1):

Long-ish response to Niklas B.'s comment:

I decided to test this, and here are the results. Blue dots are your function, green are Mario's; y axis is runtime in seconds, x axis is len(nums).
[image]

As you said, both are O(n). Yours is faster up to about 45 items; for anything over 100 items, his is roughly twice as fast.

It's mostly irrelevant - this seems to be more of a beginner syntax question than anything else - and, as you say, Python isn't a speed demon to begin with. On the other hand, who doesn't like a bit more speed (so long as readability doesn't suffer)?

For those interested, here's the code I wrote to test this:

```
from random import randint
from timeit import Timer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gt1(nums, n):
    # based on Niklas B.'s answer - NOTE comparison is corrected
    return n < max(nums)

def gt2(nums, n):
    # based on Mario Fernandez's answer
    return any(e > n for e in nums)

def make_data(length, lo=0, hi=None):
    if hi is None:
        hi = lo + length - 1
    elif lo > hi:
        lo,hi = hi,lo
    return [randint(lo, hi) for i in xrange(length)]

def make_args(d):
    nums = make_data(d)
    n = randint(0,d)
    return "{}, {}".format(nums, n)

def time_functions(fns, domain, make_args, reps=10, number=10):
    fns = [fn.__name__ if callable(fn) else fn for fn in fns]
    data = [[] for fn in fns]
    for d in domain:
        for r in xrange(reps):
            args = make_args(d)
            for i,fn in enumerate(fns):
                timer = Timer(
                    setup='from __main__ import {}'.format(fn),
                    stmt='{}({})'.format(fn, make_args(d))
                )
                data[i].extend((d,res) for res in timer.repeat(number=number))
    return data

def plot_data(data, formats=None):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    if formats is None:
        for d in data:
            ax.plot([x for x,y in d], [y for x,y in d])
    else:
        for d,f in zip(data, formats):
            ax.plot([x for x,y in d], [y for x,y in d], f)
    plt.show()

def main():
    data = time_functions([gt1, gt2], xrange(10, 501, 10), make_args)
    plot_data(data, ['bo', 'g.'])

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Of course, the expected constant difference is factor 2, because in a randomly distributed array, the middle element will be the hit we're looking for in the array. This is only the case because you always choose an element that is in the range of the array. If you compare the cases where `n` is actually greater than all the elements, or even only greater than 75% of it, the results will look radically different. As I said, it all depends on the input (and that's why I added another comment to my earlier comment, saying that there's no point in arguing about performance here).

Comment: That is, we can't say anything about the average case, because we don't have any statistical information about the input. We can only say something about the worst-case, which is equally bad in both cases. For example, just look at happens if you change `n = randint(0, d)` to `n = randint(0, int(1.5*d))`

Answer (score 0):

This could be better

```
def gt(nums, n):
    for c in nums:
       if n < c:
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: You definitely need only one loop